# Generic type indexing. TS2536: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I will appreciate it a lot if you could suggest what would be a correct way to type the method below:

```
interface TestT {
    [index: string]: any
}

function _defaultUpdateStateMutation<T extends TestT> (
    state: T,
    options: {
        value: Object,
        valueName: string
    }
) {
    const { value, valueName } = options

    // TS2536: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
    if (valueName) {
        state[valueName] = value
    } else if (value) {
        Object.keys(value).forEach(valueName => {
            state[valueName] = value[valueName]
        })
    }
}
```

TypeScript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5lcg3gKGSOQG1QATCADwC5kspQBzAXTrhAE98BfffGAFcQCMMAD2IZAH1K8QQBswAVQAO5OJADKYTRACyg3WMkAeHNUghyGNJmwA%20ZAApCxLHrqoANG6LjVExAMOgJicOQANzgFQQg6AHkAIwArCFFfCOJo2IgAOTgAW3j6MEYQJj9kPgBKPCqESSw8KJi471bcguLq5ABeZACgjH5w4BgXHLjuiDqwrNK9Ein8oogWfs64qp5kCAUMFHHJttn6heRktNEAOgBrCE4MZxWam5hxKABRRAALF9OM36TnmFyIHkgy0Baw2AxWUK6MKq4R4NR2vCAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must tell the `ts` compiler that `valueName` is key of T:

And also convert `Object.keys(value)` as a `Array<keyof T>`

```
function _defaultUpdateStateMutation<T extends TestT> (
    state: T,
    options: {
        value: any,
        valueName: keyof T
    }
) {
    const { value, valueName } = options

    if (valueName) {
        state[valueName] = value
    } else if (value) {
        (Object.keys(value) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(valueName => {
            state[valueName] = value[valueName]
        })
    }
}
```

[PlayGroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5lcg3gKGSOQG1QATCADwC5kspQBzAXTrhAE98BfffGAFcQCMMAD2IZAH1K8QQBswAVQAO5OJADKYTRACyg3WMkAeHNUghyGNJmwA%20ZAApCxLHrqoANG6LjVExAMOgJicOQANzgFQQh2Ll8I4mjYiAA5OABbeOQAawhOcRg0P2Q%20AEo8MoRJLDwomLjvRrTMnPLkAF5kAKCMfnDgEudUuPaIKrDk%20mMIEjGM7IgWbta4sp5kCAUMFGGXRamy8OcAeQAjACsIUQA6As4MUabJ5DhbAEEoKDhOU0exTQDgqdxg4igAFFEAALF5tZbdJzTGbuOYLV4TVY9RYYhE5FgnYg8CqbXhAA)